# How can I use special characters for making folder in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "folder=C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\!!Test05\Test06"

md %folder%\Final

echo %folder%
pause
```

This will create in `C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\Test05\Test06\Final`.

Result should be like `C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\!!Test05\Test06\Final`.

How can I use special characters (`!!Test05`) for making folder in batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, exclamation marks are lost when stating them literally or when expanding normal `%`-variables. Toggle delayed expansion and read affected variables with surrounding `!` only to overcome this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Delayed Expansion is disabled, so literal exclamation marks are maintained:
set "folder=C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\!!Test05\Test06"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Delayed Expansion is enabled, so do not expand variables with `%`,
rem    or you will lose exclamation marks: */
md "!folder!\Final"
endlocal

rem /* Delayed Expansion is disabled, variables can be expanded with `%`,
rem    without losing exclamation marks: */
echo "%folder%"
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

for this, since windows treats ! as a special character you are going to need to escape it. the ^ symbol is an escape character so something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "folder=C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\^!^!Test05\Test06"

md %folder%\Final

echo %folder%
pause
```

Should work fine. Take a look here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: Thanks for helping
sorry still it s not working. i means folder name should be "!!Test05"

Comment: @SandeepPrasad if you run this line: md "C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\^!^!Test05\Test06\Final"
does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks but i need to store in veriable

Comment: I understand, i just wanted to know if it works, presumably then its the storing it part that is causing the issue, so we can work on that

Comment: yes its working (md "C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\^!^!Test05\Test06\Final")

Answer (score 0):

Your command works fine if you remove the unused and unwanted second line. **!** is not a special character in Windows but it is interpreted in a special way when you have enabled delayed expansion.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "folder=C:\Test\Test01\Test02\Test03\Test04\!!Test05\Test06"
MD "%folder%\Final"
Echo=%folder%
Timeout -1
```

Delayed Expansion is off by default although this can be changed. If you need to ensure that your **`!`** are seen correctly then the safest option would be to add the line `SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion` prior to your specific code section.